# Eclipse C++ CDT Kepler not showing console output until the end of execution

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

After I build a program, and run it, the console stays empty, while it's waiting for my scanf prompts, after pressing "Enter" on the console window in Eclipse, everything prints out, almost as if the whole buffer is being saved somewhere and then printed out. Is there a way to show the output on the console as it's being printed, and not wait until the end of execution to print everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line `fflush(stdout);` after ther first output `printf` statement...this will work fine

read this post as a reference:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732

Comment: The workaround in Comment 38 in the bug report works for me:
    set new-console on